# What Angular UI files do I need to send my developer?

Tags: angular, user-interface

I am new to using Angular, but recently I designed a User Interface (UI) for an Angular app. I want to pass it over to the Angular app developer to build functionality onto the UI. The developer lives in another part of the world. 
What files do I need to send him in order for him to build onto the UI that I designed?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Send html, css, images and if the developer has some knowledge in photoshop send the .psd files too.

Answer (score 0):

If you built the application with a UI designer then you should send over the project that the UI designer gave you when exporting.

Other than that going to need a little bit more context as to what you have created yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. To answer your question, regarding adding more context as to what I created In my UI design, I added the Material toolbar component API via `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';` and off course edited the CSS to customise the look and colour.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the **node_module** folder from your application repository and then send the entire repository to the developer. Developer can run **'npm install'** and get all the dependencies.

How it works is that in **package.json** file you will have one dependencies object where all the required module for run your app are mentioned. So when **npm install** is executed, **node_modules** folder will be created and it will contain all the required packages.

Always use *--save* flag with *npm install package_name*. It register the package name in package.json.